# How do you print every k-letter block in a string until the end of the string?

Tags: python

Basically, I have a long string, and I want to do something like:

```
for x in range(3,10):
   #when x = 3, break the string in blocks of 3, when x = 4, break it into blocks of 4, etc.
```

So, for example, if the string is equal to "hello_world" and x = 5, then I want to return {hello, _worl, d}.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way of doing this in Python comes from the [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#recipes) page

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

result = [''.join(group) for group in grouper('hello_world', 5, fillvalue="")]
```

results in:

```
Out[4]: ['hello', '_worl', 'd']
```

Comment: This is - by far - the fastest answer proposed so far.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, it relies on python elegantly slicing arrays shorter than requested (ie `"this_string"[2:400]` will return `"is_string"` without error).

```
string = "hello_world"
for x in range(3, 10):
    split = [string[(i*x):(i+1)*x] for i in range(1 + len(string) / x)]
    print(split)
```

Comment: Though this works, and takes advantage of some of Python's nicest properties, it is significantly slower than other methods proposed. In a quick test with a very large string, this code took 61s to run, as opposed to 13s with my solution using a `while` loop, and 8s for Adam Smith's even faster `itertools` answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. We're relying on the fact that the `while` loop will run one last time even if there's only one character left (like `"d"`), and that we can take a slice that is longer than the actual string, and it will just return whatever is left.

```
in_string = "hello_world"
sep = 5

chunks = []
i = 0
while (sep * len(chunks) < len(in_string)):
    chunks.append(in_string[sep*i:sep*(i+1)])
    i += 1

print chunks
```

Comment: The more time I spend in Python, the more I feel that any `while` loop that's not `while True` is not the best way to approach a problem. Check out my grouper answer from the `itertools` recipes docs page

Comment: Good call! Your method does appear to be significantly faster, too! I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nifty little recursive function to do it:

```
def splitter(word, n):
    if len(word) > n:
        return [word[:n]] + splitter(word[n:],n)
    else:
        return [word]

>>> splitter("hello_world", 5)
['hello', '_worl', 'd']
```

Comment: Recursion is dangerous here, as large strings will cause a `RuntimeError:  maximum recursion depth exceeded`. It's also quite slow.